# Combine multiple resultsets

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have multiple conditions wise stored procedures and I want to combine result sets into single procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TotalReceivedUnits_Country]
@ContractCode NVARCHAR (20), 
@CountryCode NVARCHAR (10),
@Years NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(S.NettoWeight), 0) TotalNettoWeight, COUNT(S.ShipmentID) Loads, ReceivalDateYear = YEAR(S.ReceivalDate)
        FROM   Shipment S
        WHERE S.ContractCode = @ContractCode AND 
              S.[OrigCountryCode] = @CountryCode AND
              S.ClosedYN = 0 AND 
              S.Shipped = 1 AND
              S.DeletedYN = 0 AND
              S.OutInbound = 2 AND
              YEAR(S.ReceivalDate) IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Years, ','))
        GROUP BY YEAR(S.ReceivalDate)
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TotalProcessedUnits_Country]
@ContractCode NVARCHAR (20), 
@CountryCode NVARCHAR (10),
@Years NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(S.NettoWeight), 0) TotalNettoWeight, COUNT(S.ShipmentID) Loads, ReceivalDateYear = YEAR(S.ReceivalDate)
    FROM   Shipment S with (nolock)
    WHERE S.ContractCode = @ContractCode AND 
          S.OrigCountryCode = @CountryCode AND
          S.ClosedYN = 1 AND 
          S.Shipped = 1 AND
          S.FinanceDetailsYN = 0 AND
          S.DeletedYN = 0 AND
          S.OutInbound = 2 AND
          YEAR(S.ReceivalDate) IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@Years, ','))
    GROUP BY YEAR(S.ReceivalDate)
END
GO
```

Above two procedures have same result counts by processed and received summary but How can I combine them to one query with multiple conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to load the outputs into temp tables and then select:

```
CREATE TABLE #out1(TotalNettoWeight INT, Loads INT, ReceivalDateYear DATETIME2);
CREATE TABLE #out2(TotalNettoWeight INT, Loads INT, ReceivalDateYear DATETIME2);
GO

INSERT #out1
EXEC [dbo].[usp_TotalReceivedUnits_Country] 123,6,10;

INSERT #out2
EXEC [dbo].[usp_TotalProcessedUnits_Country] 123,6,10;
GO

SELECT * FROM #out1
UNION
SELECT * FROM #out2
GO

DROP TABLE #out1;
DROP TABLE #out2;
GO
```